# how to append row index value to ID of td

Tags: javascript, html, dust.js

This is my code:

```
<tbody>
{#participants}
<tr>
    <td id="id">{.fullName}</td>
</tr>
{/participants}
```

I am writing this code in .dust file. I want to append row index value to my td's ID. Is there any way to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot have duplicated `id`. What exactly you want to do? This looks like a XY problem to me.

Comment: As @PraveenKumar says, IDs must be unique - and (IMHO) don't really make sense as purely numeric values.  I'd look at using a data-* attribute.

Comment: @Praveen : Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question for better understanding. I want to append row index value to id of TD

Comment: First of all, your `HTML` code has issues, missing openning `<font>` tag for example. Regarding your problem, why can't you simply do: `<td id="id_{.id}">{.fullName}</td>`?

Comment: @lonut : Your logic is very good. I will try to add another field like id in my actual list.

Answer (score 1):

`{$idx}` will give you the current index.

Example

```
<tr>
    <td id="id_{$idx}">{.fullName}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the index from your database row? Then you might want to to something like:

```
<td id="id_{.id}">{.fullName}</td>
```

...where `{.id}` contains the value of the ID of the row. this would be the best method, as it required no javascript, this method is fastest.